# Mysql query and php work out that can get items from DB and do the average

Tags: php, mysql

I have a stock table that has several items oderd by users and the item can be having different unit prices depending on the time they were ordered, so you can find an item has more than 5 entries with different prices like the below table:

```
+----+----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
| ID | unitCost | quantity | totalPrice | orderNumber | item  |
+----+----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
|  1 |       20 |        5 |        100 | OD003       | Pen   |
|  2 |       15 |        3 |         45 | OD004       | Pen   |
|  3 |       22 |       10 |        220 | OD005       | Books |
|  4 |       13 |        7 |         91 | OD006       | Pen   |
+----+----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
```

So am trying to get 10 pens from the table. And the logic should be like this
When I take the first and they are not enough from the first row, I will go to the next row and get the remaining quantity and if it will not be enough it will go to the next till I get the 10 pens that I needed.
Then the price of the 10 pens I get from the table will be the average of unit price of each pen i got.

Please help me solve this in mysql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get the result from mysql and put it inside array to loop it.

```
$total_order = 40; $price = 0;
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['quantity'] < $total_order) {
        $price += $value['quantity']*$value['unitCost'];
    } else {
        $price += $total_order*$value['unitCost'];
        break; //exit loop and stop calculating
    }
    $total_order = $total_order-$value['quantity'];
}
```

You may need to tweak the code above a bit to meet your criteria. e.g: Pen price only.

Comment: hello bugscoder, i have tried the below, please help